# Find the limit of the vector function

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, vectors, parametric

$lim_{t\to\infty} \Big(te^{-t},\frac{t^3+t}{2t^3-1},tsin(\frac{1}{t})\Big)$

a) $lim_{t\to\infty} te^{-t} = \infty \times 0$

$lim_{t\to\infty} 1e^{-t}+-e^tt = 0+(0\times\infty)$=undefined, and repeating l'hospitals rule will render the same result over and over.

b) $lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t^3+t}{2t^3-1} = \frac{\infty}{\infty}$

$lim_{t\to\infty}6=6$  (simpflifying using l'hospitals rule)

c) $lim_{t\to\infty} tsin\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big) = \infty \times 0$

$lim_{t\to\infty} 1sin\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big)+cos\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big)\frac{-t}{t^2}= \lim_{t\to\infty} sin\Big(\frac{1}{\infty}\Big)+cos\Big(\frac{1}{\infty}\Big)\frac{-1}{\infty} = 0+(1\times0)=0$

$lim_{t\to\infty}\Big(te^{-t},\frac{t^3+t}{st^3-1},tsin(\frac{1}{t})\Big) = \Big(idk,6,0\Big)$

Are b and c correct? I am not sure what to do about a and this is an even numbered exercise in my book so idk what the answer is.

Comment: Is that s in the second coordinate supposed to be a 2?

Comment: yes i will fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a)
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}te^{-t}=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{t}{e^t}=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{1}{e^t}=0$$
(b)
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{t^3+t}{2t^3-1}=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{1+1/t^2}{2-1/t^3}=\frac{1}{2}$$
(c)
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}t\sin \frac{1}{t}=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{\sin\frac{1}{t}}{\frac{1}{t}}=\lim_{\frac{1}{t}\to 0}\frac{\sin\frac{1}{t}}{\frac{1}{t}}=1$$

(a) Using L'Hopital's rule in the second step.

(b) No need to use L'Hopital's rule, but if you want, it will be
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{t^3+t}{2t^3-1}=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{3t^2+1}{6t^2}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{6t}{12t}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{6}{12}=\frac{1}{2}$$

(c) The last step is well known. But if you want L'Hopital's rule, it is
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x}{1}=1$$
where $x=1/t$.

Comment: The only issue I have is the last step. Where can I learn that? I referring to the the change $t\to\infty$ to $\frac{1}{t} \to 0$ how can \frac{1}{t} approach 0? that seems undefined to me when substituted... i really need to brush up on some concepts.

Comment: I found some info here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#Other_methods_of_evaluating_limits under other methods of evaluating and it seems your notation is off. In the third step the chain rule is applied on the top and and they cancel out to get one on the bottom but the notation never changes to the limit approaching 0.

Comment: If you continue reading few lines after the link you posted you'll find the change of variabile and the limit going to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mistaken in your use of L'Hopital's Rule. To properly evaluate a limit of the form $0\cdot\infty$, you must convert it to an equivalent one of the form $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$.

For the first limit, using $te^{-t}=t/e^t$ will work just fine.

For the second limit, we have a limit of proper form, but the derivatives appear to have been derived incorrectly. Using L'Hopital's rule once more yields

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{t^3+t}{2t^3-1}=\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{3t^2+1}{6t^2}=\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{6t}{12t}=\frac{1}{2}$$

For the final limit, we can create a proper form by using $t\sin(1/t)=(\sin(1/t))/(1/t)$. Thus,

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}t\sin(1/t)=\lim_{1/t\to0}\frac{\sin(1/t)}{1/t}=1$$

Comment: Clever rearrangement on the third one and I appreciate the clarification on the l'hosptials rule.